# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'siteSettingsData' of 'data' as it is undefined

Tags: next.js, sanity

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'siteSettingsData' of 'data' as
> it is undefined.

Give this error when I'm going to pass data from a component but work fine on index page

```
 import React from 'react'
    import client from '../lib/sanity';
    
    
    export default function Home({ data }) {
        const { siteSettingsData } = data;
      
        return (
          <>
    
            <h1 className="site-header__logo">{siteSettingsData.title}</h1>
    
          </>
        );
      }
      
      const siteSettingsQuery = `*[_type == "siteSettings"][0] {
        title,
        repoURL {
          current
        }
      }`;
      
      export async function getStaticProps() {
        const siteSettingsData = await client.fetch(siteSettingsQuery);
      
        const data = { siteSettingsData };
      
        return {
          props: {
            data,
          },
          revalidate: 1,
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do to solve the problem:

1. `console.log(data)` to see what you are receiving
2. Go to the file that is passing `props` to `Home`, to see whether `data` key has been added. If it has, it should also include the `siteSettingsData` key within the `data object`.

More about `props` on the `React` website: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: data is coming when I'm trying from the index.js

Comment: @raqibnur, if you're still stuck, I can have a look at the repository. Is `data` an `object`? Do you need to `await` the `data`, before destructuring it? Maybe it's loaded after.